# Modifying Parent Scope within "Invoke-Command" cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for a way to modify the parent scope from within the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet. (This is mainly to log errors when running this command in a loop for a set of domain nodes.) Here's a simplified example of a failed attempt which should illustrate my intention.

```
$comps = "comp 1", "comp 2", "comp 3"
$Global:errorList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]

$comps | ForEach-Object {
    
    $currComp = $_

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock {
        
        Try { <# Do a bunch of stuff here... #> }
        Catch { $Global:errorList.Add( @{ 'Hostname' = $currComp ; 'Exception' = $_.Exception.Message} ) }
    
    } -Credential $cred
}
```

This of course doesn't work. Neither if `$Global:` is replaced with `$Using:`. I haven't tried the `$Env:` scope but I'm assuming this won't work and even if it does, I'd prefer not create an environment variable just for this purpose if there's an alternative. Any ideas? Is it possible to make updates to the parent scope from within these remote commands (same would apply for `New-PSSession`, I assume)?

Comment: I'm afraid you won't be able to do that. One thing you can try is to return the data you need to be added in the global scope from the invoke command, and add it outside the Invoke-Command block.